# Controlling 30 LEDs with 2 PCA9685 boards - need to increase performance

Tags: python, i2c, pwm

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and two [Adafruit PCA9685 interfaces](https://www.adafruit.com/product/815) with which I am trying to control 30 white LEDs.

Currently, I am using Python and [Adafruit's module](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_PCA9685), this works fine, however, with the module's [`set_pwm` function](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_PCA9685/blob/master/Adafruit_PCA9685/PCA9685.py#L102), I can only control one LED at a time, which is very slow and results in flickering LEDs.

Are there better ways to do this, can I for example set all LEDs at once?

Comment: The PCA9685 lets you set either one (1) channel or all (16) channels.  You can't set 2-15 channels in one operation.  You need to explain how you want to be able to control the LEDs.  E.g. individually or as a group etc.

Comment: To clarify when you set all channels they are all set to the same value.

Comment: Thanks! I need to control the LEDs individually, and play patterns at a reasonable frame rate.

Comment: I've been able to improve the frame rate a lot by increasing the i2c baud rate: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/02/change-raspberry-pi-i2c-bus-speed/.